# Twitter icon not showing on uiactivitycontroller in ios 7

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

i configured twitter properly in setting menu, my problem is only twitter string is showing on `UIActivityViewController`, can anyone help me how can i display twitter icon?

```
NSString *shareString = @"Welcome.";
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome.png"];
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.welcome.com"];

NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString, shareImage, shareUrl, nil];

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Post your code, without it we can't help you.

Comment: @ rckoenes i have posted my code above

Comment: Please post what is in the `activityItems`!

Comment: Are you testing it on a real device which has got Twitter installed?

Comment: yes i am testing on my real device and it is configured properly.